How to check if two values ​match in different "google sheets" with google apps script?
I've been building a script for a few days which I wanted to do the following:

From a database (generated from a forms) collect specific data from the students  (I'm going to high school)

Based on a template, from a different document, fill it with the students' data that's been collected

And when the time comes to check which teacher they have, if the data (of the student) of the course they are in and the classroom to which they belong coincide with those of any of the teachers in another database ( in a different Google Sheets), an email has to be sent to the teacher because of they be able to see the document with their specific students' data


​ var templateCopy= template.makeCopy("ficha_individual: " + actualSheet.getRange("C" + fila).getValue());

var document = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateCopy.getId());

var course = actualSheet.getRange("L" + fila).getValue();

var class = actualSheet.getRange("M" + fila).getValue();

var teachersheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById("IDFORMTHETEACHERSHEET");

var lastRow = teachersheets .getLastRow();

var teachercourse= teachersheets.getRange("D2:D" + lastRow).getValues();

var teacherclass= teachersheets.getRange("E2:E" + lastRow).getValues();

var teacherMail= teachersheets.getRange("B2:B" + lastRow).getValues();

if (course && class == teachercourse && teacherclass) {
document.addEditor(teacherMail)} 

else { ui.alert("There's no teacher for the students") }


​The problem is that I don't quite understand how to go through the rows and columns of the spreadsheet in which the teachers' data is found in order to see if it matches with the students data.
I principaly want that it sends an Email to the one that is registered from the forms if the data from the same row on the besides columns matches


From a database (generated from a forms) collect specific data from the students

Google Forms data can automatically be saved in a Google Sheet. See Choose where to save form responses.

Based on a template, from a different document, fill it with the students' data that's been collected

Use filter() to collect the data, and join() to put all matches for a teacher in the same row as that teacher's data. See filter(), join() and textjoin().

email has to be sent to the teacher because of they be able to see the document with their specific students' data

That is a "mail merge" use case. You may want to try AutoCrat instead of writing your own code. For other options, choose Extensions > Add-ons > Get add-ons and search for  mail merge. See mail merge.
